# Bcrypt fails to install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bcrypt

I am having problems installing an npm package called "bcrypt" on my Ubuntu system.

**This is what I did:**

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install nodejs
>   sudo apt-get install npm
>   sudo npm install bcrypt

**This is what I got:**

when typing: sudo npm install bcrypt

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/1.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/1.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.0.0

> bcrypt@0.8.0 install /home/gatsu/salongapp/salongapp/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-35-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/gatsu/salongapp/salongapp/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The package does **not** get placed in this folder:

> /home/gatsu/salongapp/salongapp/node_modules/bcrypt

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

in ubuntu if you install nodejs using apt, the command for nodejs will be `nodejs` while commonly command line name used for nodejs is `node`.

Here, bcrypt assumes the command as `node` which is not available.

Try setting alias for nodejs as node like this
`alias node='nodejs'`
and then try to install bcrypt
`sudo npm install bcrypt`

U can set aliases in `.bash_aliases` file in home folder to permanently set the alias node.

Comment: I appended `alias node='nodejs'` to my `~/.bash_aliases` but the same error persist

Comment: try restart shell using `bash -l`

Comment: `bash -l` did nothing so I just rebooted my computer but the error is still haunting me.